# Asking for "other" user password while restarting a service

Tags: permissions, apache2, sudo

I am normal user with `sudo` privileges. I just installed `apache2` and when tried to restart the service, it asked for the password of another `sudo` user in the system.

I can restart like `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. But why it is behaving like this?

**Details::**

[image]

```
givinv@87-109:~$ 
givinv@87-109:~$ uname -a
Linux 87-109 4.4.0-47-generic #68-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 26 19:39:52 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
givinv@87-109:~$ 
givinv@87-109:~$ 
givinv@87-109:~$ apachectl -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2016-07-14T12:32:26
givinv@87-109:~$ 
givinv@87-109:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers | grep 'ashu\|givin'
ashutosh ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
givinv ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
givinv  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
givinv@87-109:~$ 
givinv@87-109:~$
```

Is it related to `apache2` or `sudo user` ? Please let me know if more details needed.

Comment: When you run `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` which user's password is required?

Comment: It doesn't require password as I mentioned `givinv  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` in `sudoers` file.  I just removed that line from `sudoers` file and tried, it was asking for the same`(givinv)` user password.

Comment: Is your `apache` run under user **ashutosh**?

Comment: No. I installed it with the same user.


`givinv@87-109:~$ sudo find /etc/ -name apache2 | xargs ls -l | grep ashu | wc -l
0
givinv@87-109:~$ `

Comment: The process run as `www-data` user.

Comment: Thanks, that was it ! sudo group was added in file inside `etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/`. My user was not added in that group.